# my spa motor stopped running

Tags: pump, motor

my spa pump motor stopped running. I had the motor tested and it was fine. it is a 240 motor on a 20 amp double breaker, but I am only getting 120 at the switch and motor. is the breaker bad?

Comment: What voltage do you measure across the lugs at the breaker?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: i see it now. i got 104

Comment: What make and model is your breaker box, and what make and model is the breaker in question? Are there other 240V loads on that breaker box, for that matter?

Comment: there are 2 dedicated 240 breakers. one only runs the pump for the wave seat in my spa. It reads 244 and the pump works. the other only runs the filter pump. It reads 104 and the pump does not run.

Comment: The panel on the breaker box says Magnatrip load center. Zinsco electrical products.

Comment: I do not know the make of the breakers themselves.

Comment: Jeff Zinsco breakers , I hope this is a small sub see my answer.

Comment: @jeff -- can you post photos of the panel then please, and what size (height by width by depth) is it for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

Ok Zinsco were great in the day but the aluminum bussbars had a bigger issue if not coated with noalox.
To me it sounds like a contact failure:
One of the contact points can start arcing and no longer provide 240 but only 120 (each hot leg provides 120 to ground).

Any buss bar arcing can over heat the breaker and prevent it from tripping.
For this reason Zinsco panels are no longer covered by some insurance companies.

I installed hundreds of these panels the first in my moms house and I have inspected it because it is close to the coast , but I have found others damaged by arcing that did not have corrosion protection. My moms is still good and as my brother and I own the home I would change it out in a second if I though it was sketchy.

Once a breaker position arcs that position is no longer viable. Some say the entire panel is not viable.

I would have a pro check the panel but be prepared to replace it.
As I said any arcing that position is dead as the breaker is no longer good.

Comment: Ed:  Agreed completely.  I used to work in a hardware store when I was going to college (Pay 'N Pack, now defunct) and sold a bunch of Zinsco panels. Even as a college punk I was considered the electrical expert!  But yes, I would recommend replacement of the panel in any event. They have a high failure rate and as you mentioned many insurance companies won't even insure a structure with a Zinsco panel.   The OP should get this panel replaced now and have a safer electrical service to enjoy now. It'll have to be done at some point anyway.